# How to upload image file using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want upload image file on server & want to stored image in database.

How can I store image file in database & also get the image file from database. Please help  to solved this problem.

i have done this code in project..
but when uploading image on server upload_path not found.
In controller

```
 $config['upload_path'] = base_url().'aplication/upload/'; // the uploaded images path
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';/*types of image extentions allowed to be uploaded*/
        $config['max_size'] = '3048';// maximum file size that can be uploaded (2MB)
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) /* this checks to see if the file path is wrong or does not exist.*/
        {
            echo( $config['upload_path']);
            die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST"); // error for invalid file path
        $this->load->library('upload',$config); /* this loads codeigniters file upload library*/
        }


        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload() )
        {
            $error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            //echo "UPLOAD ERROR ! ".$this->upload->display_errors(); //image error
            //  $this->load->view('main_view',$error);
        }
        else
        {
            $file_data=$this->upload->data();
            $data['img']=base_url().'.application/upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];
            echo("Image upload successfully..");
//================================================

            // $this->load->model('insert_model');
            //  $this->insert_model->submit_image();

//==========================================
            //$this->insert_model->insert_images($this->upload->data());
            // $this->load->model('insert_model');
            //$this->insert_model->submit_image();


        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [image uploading with codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942477/image-uploading-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

That is quite easy. Just create image upload function once in your controller. Here is one function I wrote:

```
function image_upload($path, $size, $width, $height, $new_name, $ext)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = $size;
    $config['file_name'] = time() . $new_name . "." . $ext;
    $config['max_width'] = $width;
    $config['max_height'] = $height;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); //Load codeigniter's file upload library
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return $config['file_name'];
    }
}
```

Now in the action function of form where you have file input field call this function as follows do as follows:

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != "")//Check if file was selected by the user
{
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//Get the extension of file
    $picture_name = $this->image_upload("your/upload/directory/", 10000, 10000, 100000, "test", $ext);
    //Now save this $picture_name in database

}
else
{
    print_r($this->upload->display_errors());//Display errors if file does not get uploaded successfully
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Read **[This](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)**, then you will get how to upload file.

Now how to store it into DB.!

In controller use this :

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
                {   

                        $img_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());                          
                        $full_url = "/uploads/".$img_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                        $reply = $this->model_name->upload_image($full_url);


                }
```

In model using `upload_image($full_url)` function store image name with path, so that you can get back that path whenever needed.